# Including parsys with same path twice AEM?

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am aware that including parsys with same path on the same Page/component causes authoring issues.

```
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="/apps/myproj/components/layout/parsys" /> 
<cq:include path="par" resourceType="/apps/myproj/components/layout/parsys" />
```

But I have a situation where I am forced to do this.
I am actually managing the path name using a variable parameter like this

```
 <cq:include path="${tabs.nodeName}"
                      resourceType="/apps/myproj/components/layout/parsys" />
```

This is iterating in a forEach and the value of **tabs.nodeName** changes after every iteration.

But this loop itself is copied two times, once for desktop view with desktop classes and second time for mobile view with mobile css classes.

So in the end, I end up with two `cq:includes`

of the with same paths one for desktop another for mobile

```
<cq:include path="${tabs.nodeName}"
                      resourceType="/apps/myproj/components/layout/parsys" />

 <cq:include path="${tabs.nodeName}"
                      resourceType="/apps/myproj/components/layout/parsys" />
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: including parsys two times is a sub-optimal solution, include parsys only once and use responsive css, or if you really have to put the duplicate logic in individual components.

Answer (score 0):

You can add scope identificator and use it as an additional element of the path. It can be semantical (desktop/mobile) or just numerical (zero-based, incremented on each step) if you don't know the context

```
<c:set var="context" value="desktop"/>

<cq:include path="${tabs.nodeName}-${context}"
                  resourceType="/apps/myproj/components/layout/parsys" />
```

Comment: I don't think you get what I am trying to do. Changing the path like that means I would have two parsys one for mobile and the other for desktop. I want the same parsys for both so that authoring can be done only once.

Comment: I don't think it is possible then, multiple elements with the same path are not decorated properly by UI scripts, hence not usable. Proper way to handle it is to use media queries to associate proper styling with specific viewports and using only one parsys since content is the same for both presentation types

Answer (score 0):

I would advise either not rendering the mobile paragraph systems when in edit/design mode or setting the WCMMode to `disabled` when producing the mobile rendering of the paragraph systems.  In this way you maintain the ability to author once and use twice without breaking the authoring interface.